# Checking link syntax of user input

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site where users can enter comments and descriptions. I allow them to enter links in as well. I use `strip_tags` with an exception for links. I also add `rel="nofollow"` through a simple string_replace.

The problem is, if users leave off a double quote at the end of their opening tag, it messes up the html. Any suggestions on how to check for or fix incorrect link syntax?

`$comment = $_POST['comment'];`
`$comment = strip_tags($comment,"<a>");`
`$comment = str_replace('<a','<a rel="nofollow"',$comment);`
`$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($comment);`

and when outputting

$comment = stripslashes($comment);

echo $comment;

The problem is when users add `<a href="www.blah.com>` and forget the last double quote, this messes up the way the comment div displays.

Comment: I meant, the PHP code with the str_replace you do for the rel="nofollow"

Comment: Sorry. My first time on StackOverflow. That should do it.

Comment: Probably a little overkill, but you may find [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what you have to do:

```
function fixLink($link) {
    $link = str_replace(array('<a', '"', '</a>'), '', $link);
    $link = str_replace(
        array('=', '>', ' '),
        array('="', '">', '" '),
        $link);
    return '<a rel="nofollow' . $link . '</a>';
}    

echo fixLink('<a href="/index.html>asd</a>') . "\n";
echo fixLink('<a class="awesome" href="/index.html>asd</a>') . "\n";
echo fixLink('<a href="/index.html class="awesome">asd</a>') . "\n";
echo fixLink('<a target="_blank" href="/index.html class="awesome">asd</a>') . "\n";
echo fixLink('<a target="_blank" href="/index.html class="awesome>asd</a>') . "\n";
echo fixLink('<a target="_blank" href="/index.html target="_blank" class="awesome">asd</a>') . "\n";
echo fixLink('<a href="/index.html class=awesome">asd</a>') . "\n";
```

That will output:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/index.html">asd</a>
<a rel="nofollow" class="awesome" href="/index.html">asd</a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="/index.html" class="awesome">asd</a>
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/index.html" class="awesome">asd</a>
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/index.html" class="awesome">asd</a>
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/index.html" target="_blank" class="awesome">asd</a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="/index.html" class="awesome">asd</a>
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you BoZ. This seems like something that would be a common issue, but I wasn't able to find anything on it. This fix should work fine. Thanks again.

Comment: glad you liked it. I hope it's the best answer you can find.